# VB - How do you remove "empty" items from a generic list?

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET (2010) project that contains a generic list, and I'm trying to figure out how to remove any "empty" items from the list. When I say "empty", I mean any item that does not contain any actual characters (but it may contain any amount of whitespace, or no whitespace at all).

For example, let's say this is my list...

```
    Dim MyList As New List(Of String)

    MyList.Add("a")
    MyList.Add("")
    MyList.Add("b")
    MyList.Add(" ")
    MyList.Add("c")
    MyList.Add("      ")
    MyList.Add("d")
```

I need it so that if I did a count on that list, it would return 4 items, instead of 7. For example...

```
    Dim ListCount As Integer = MyList.Count
    MessageBox.Show(ListCount) ' Should show "4"
```

It would be nice if there was something like...

```
    MyList.RemoveEmpty
```

Anyways... I've been searching Google for a solution to this for the past few hours, but haven't been able to turn up anything so far. So... any ideas?

BTW, I'm targeting the .NET 2.0 framework for this project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need to preserve the "empty" items for later, or do you want them permanently removed?

Comment: Permanently removed would be great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wdka673a.aspx)

```
MyList.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
```

If you don't use at least .NET 4, you can't use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx). Then you can implement the method yourself:

```
Public Shared Function IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value As String) As Boolean
    If value Is Nothing Then
        Return True
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
        If Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(value(i)) Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Note that [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa311613%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is there since 1.1.

Comment: Gah beaten by a bit more, had to look up VB.net :)

Comment: I think you get bonus points for having List.RemoveAll in the code typeface, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, guys. But when I pasted that line into the program, I get the following error... "IsNullOrWhiteSpace" is not a member of String. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I just added that function, but still getting the same error. I pasted everything exactly as you wrote it. Do I need to substitute anything in that code, perhaps? I appreciate all your help!

Comment: I figured it out. For the "RemoveAll" line, I changed it to --> `MyList.RemoveAll(Function(str) IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))`    Thanks again Tim... you have been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

The post marked as solution didn't works for me.

Try this:

```
MyList.AsEnumerable().Where(Function (x) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList
```

This must returns you a list without empty values.