# Remove all empty elements from string array

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, list

I have this:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>{"", "a", "", "b", "", "c"};
```

I want to remove all the empty elements `("")` from it quickly (probably through LINQ) without using a `foreach` statement because that makes the code look ugly.

Comment: Nearly a duplicate: [How do you remove “empty” items from a generic list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12849528/256431)

Comment: Btw, that's not a `string` array but a list.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

C#

```
s.RemoveAll(str => String.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
```

VB.NET

```
s.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
```

Comment: I would simply write `s.RemoveAll(String.IsNullOrEmpty);`, you don't need a lambda in this case.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: +1 Good point. But at least in VB.NET it isn't really shorter: `s.RemoveAll(AddressOf String.IsNullOrEmpty)` and the lamdba shows that it's possible to modify it easily. Imho it's more readable with the lambda.

Comment: Why is it returning number of removed elements instead of cleared list? This `int count = s.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty);` is valid but `List<string> list = s.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty);` not.

Comment: Because creating a new list with the removed elements would be a much more expensive operation than simply returning the count of removed elements. Note that the method should only remove elements and the return value is just an information that can be provided because it's already available. If you need to get a list of matching elements have a look at List.FindAll.

Answer (score 14):

Check out with *[`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)* with [*`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method;

> Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.

```
s.RemoveAll(str => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
```

Here is a *[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/dYU07Z)*.

Answer (score 11):

```
s = s.Where(val => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not correct should be s = s.Where(val => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(val)).ToList(); his Initial type is `List<string>` so you need to make sure it stays a `List<string>`

Comment: this way probably works IList. IList does not have RemoveAll.

Answer (score 0):

I write below code to remove the blank value

```
List<string> s = new List<string>{"", "a", "", "b", "", "c"};
s = s.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t)).Distinct().ToList();
```